# The EncryptedKey clause was not wrapped with the required encryption token 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken'

Tags: c#, wcf, x509

I have just added a security layer to my WCF service, and I am getting an exception in the trace log saying The EncryptedKey clause was not wrapped with the required encryption token 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken'.

I have been searching and searching to no end, does anyone know what could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was not really related to the service itself, but to my custom implementation of MembershipProvider and my password security implementation. I have done the necessary adjustments and everything works wonderfully now.

Debugging WCF errors can be quite tricky as some of the messages are cryptic if not misleading, I recommend enabling WCF tracing and also stepping through your both your service  and client code in Visual Studio. If I had done that immediately when the problem occurred instead of spending 12 hours on Google I'd have solved the problem in five minutes.

It is also very important to update the service reference in your client project after making changes to the service code.

Moral of the story: use tracing and debugging. It's worth more than gold!